# Transformations of functions

Tags: linear-transformations

The question asks for a sequence of transformations from

$$y=\ln(x) \ \ \text{to} \ \ y=-2\ln(3-4x)$$

I was fine with most of it except in the answers instead of a translation of three in the positive x direction it said negative.

The issue arises when doing a reflection in the x axis

Let's say

$f(2-x)$ is reflected in the x axis

Does the reflection do $f(-(-x+2))$ around everything or does it only affect the x part $f(-(-x)+2)$ ?

Comment: You have been around for almost two years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: See https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/function-transformations.html

Comment: Following the remark of José Carlos santos, I have corrected some of your ill-written formulas. In particular $log_e(...)$ should be written `$\ln(...)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the $x$ part: order of operations is reversed within the function when doing transformations, so to apply a mirroring last, you need to negate $x$ first. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sdg853vg9d for an example.

You might also find it helpful to rewrite $3-4x$ as $-4x+3$.